# Servlet Filter: Search when no servlet mapping exists

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I would like to run a search whenever a 404 is encountered. For example, a user would like to view restaurants with Italian cuisine, they would go to www.mywebsite.com/italian so instead of showing a custom 404 error page, I would like add a filter which first checks if a 404 would have been thrown, if so, attempt to search against a list of search items, if a match exists, forward request to that page rather than throw 404 error.

Example:

```
www.mywebsite.com/italian  --> www.mywebsite.com/search.do?cuisine=italian
www.mywebsite.com/london   --> www.mywebsite.com/search.do?city=london 
www.mywebsite.com/rest     --> www.mywebsite.com/show.do?rest_id=XXX
```

The question I guess is how would I determine if there doesn't exists a servlet with `url-mapping` `"/italian"` or `"/italian/*"` within my server config?

Using (in Filter.doFilter) request.getRequestDispatcher(request.getRequestURI()) always returns a non-null value which I cannot use to determine whether the request is valid or not. I can use a 404 error statement but the result would have a response status of 404 rather than 200.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just map the 404 error page on a servlet URL pattern.

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>errorServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.ErrorServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>errorServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/error</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error</location>
</error-page>
```

This allows for doing fine grained business and HTTP request/response controlling job in the servlet before displaying the desired JSP.

Comment: I ended up using this approach to capture the 404 errors and attempt to either forward to the proper search parameter or display the default 404 page. In the case of forwarding, I had to change the response status code to 200 since a match was found.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of at least two ways to implement this:

### `<error-page>`

In your `web.xml` add:

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/notfound</location>
</error-page>
```

`/notfound` should be an existing servlet/controller that can access the original URL (the one that was not found, e.g. `/italian`) with:

```
request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.request_uri")
```

In this controller you can send redirect to `/search.do`.

### HTTP proxy

If you put HTTP proxy in front of servlet container (like Apache HTTP server) you can catch 404's sent from the server and return redirects (30x codes).

### Servlet post-filter

If you insist on servlet filter, this is doable as well. Create a filter that wraps the original response and forwards the request further. After receiving the response back from the chain check the HTTP status. If it is 404, redirect to search servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Untested: `ServletContext.getResourcePaths()` seems to list resources mapped on a given path.